# Remove decimal in shorted number where is 0

Tags: php

I used a function to make numbers short. Like 10k, 30M etc. I wish just a decimal (4.9K) but only if it is different to 0. I need 7k and not 7.0K. How i can do it? I tried with str_replace but it doesn't work.
Any solutions?

```
function num_short($n, $precision = 1) {
    if ($n < 1000) {
        $n_format = number_format($n);
    } else if ($n < 1000000) {
        $n_format = number_format($n / 1000, $precision) . 'K';
    } else if ($n < 1000000000) {
        $n_format = number_format($n / 1000000, $precision) . 'M';
    } else {
        $n_format = number_format($n / 1000000000, $precision) . 'B';
    }
    $n_format = str_replace("",".0",$n_format);
    return $n_format;
}
```

Comment: Your str_replace is backwards. Use `$n_format = str_replace(".0","",$n_format);` to eliminate the unnecessary decimal zero

Comment: Perfect.. stupid error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Amadan is up to something... something that Amadan doesn't care to explain.

You can replace your calls to `number_format` to `round`, like this:

```
function num_short($n, $precision = 1) {
    if ($n < 1000) {
        $n_format = round($n);
    } else if ($n < 1000000) {
        $n_format = round($n / 1000, $precision) . 'K';
    } else if ($n < 1000000000) {
        $n_format = round($n / 1000000, $precision) . 'M';
    } else {
        $n_format = round($n / 1000000000, $precision) . 'B';
    }
    return $n_format;
}
```

But that is only good if rounding is what you want, for example:

```
echo num_short(5000, 1); //outputs 5K
echo num_short(5400, 1); //outputs 5.4K
echo num_short(5900, 1); //outputs 5.9K
echo num_short(5990, 1); //outputs 6K
```

You can see it [working at Ideone.com](http://ideone.com/am53XN).

**note**: I have also taken the code from your question to [testing at Ideone.com](http://ideone.com/tgdWvI), it gives:

```
echo num_short(5000, 1)."\n"; //outputs 5.0K
echo num_short(5400, 1)."\n"; //outputs 5.4K
echo num_short(5900, 1)."\n"; //outputs 5.9K
echo num_short(5990, 1)."\n"; //outputs 6.0K
```

For which we can see that `number_format` rounds the same way.

Comment: Anyway precision can be omitted: num_short(5000);

Answer (score 1):

```
round($n / 1000000, $precision) . 'M'
```

EDIT: It does not remove all decimals, unless your `$n` is over the float precision limit:

```
echo round(12345678 / 1000000, 1) . 'M';
=> 12.3M
```

And fair comment from @Theraot. For no rounding, you can go with:

```
(floor($n / (1000000 / pow(10, $precision))) / pow(10, $precision)) . 'M'
```

Example:

```
echo (floor(12345678 / (1000000 / pow(10, 1))) / pow(10, 1)) . 'M';
=> 12.3M
```

Comment: +1 yup, that's the way to go for no rounding... sadly.